# Django unit test views function - example

Tags: django

I'm newbie in Django tests. How to create Unit Test for this views function? My unit test function should import function from views? Please an example. This will help me to understand how it work

```
@maintainance_job
def time_to_end(request):
    today = datetime.date.today()
    datas = Data.objects.filter(start__lte=today,
                                         other_date__gte=today)

    for data in datas:
        subject = _(u'Send email')
        body = render_to_string('mail.txt',
                                {'data': data})
        email = EmailMessage(subject, body,
                             'admin@admin.com',
                             [data.user.email])
        email.send()

    return HttpResponse('Done')
```

urls:

```
(r'^maintainance/jobs/time_to_end/$', 'content.views.time_to_end'),
```

Comment: Tests usually use paths. Please specify your url setting for the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simpliest test for your case (place it in tests.py of a directory where is your view function):

```
from django.utils import unittest
from django.test.client import Client

class HttpTester( unittest.TestCase ):
    def setUp( self ):
        self._client = Client() # init a client for local access to pages of your site

    def test_time_to_end( self ):

        response = self._client.get( '/jobs/time_to_end/' )
            # response = self._client.post( '/jobs/time_to_end/' ) - a 'POST' request

        result = response.content

        assert result != 'Done'
```

So, we use self._client to make 'get' and 'post' requests. Responses can be accessed by reading response.content (the full text of response) or by reading response.context if you use templates and want to access variables passing to the templates.

For example if your view normally must pass the dict with context variable 'result' to template:

```
{ 'result': "DONE" }
```

then you could check your result:

```
result = response.context[ 'result' ]           
assert result != 'Done'
```

So, you wait your test will have the 'result' variable and it will be 'Done'. Otherwise you raise AssertionError (note assert statement).

If there is an exception then tests fails. AssertionError is an exception too.

More details - in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/) and in a book "[Dive into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/unit_testing/index.html)".